# Android app communicate peer-to-peer using wifi-direct

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I would like to do an Android app (not for an assignment. It is a community event and I volunteered to make this app) that can send messages to peers using wifi-direct.

Basically, each phone running the app acts as a jeopardy buzzer. When a person presses the "answer" button, it disables the buttons on other people's phones (who are physically in the same room). When a question is over, all the phones have enabled "answer" buttons and so on.

I found this link below that shows how to create an app that uses wifi-direct.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/f022u9hghja7cvs/WifiDirectDemo.zip

so the question is: how do I get phones to communicate with one another through my app? Assuming their phones have wifi-direct capability, how does one phone send a message/data to other phones so that their 'answer' buttons get disabled/enabled.

I am fairly new to Android development. I have 2 days of experience with it so any kind of guidance would be useful. Thank You!

Comment: what have you tried so far? post your code here. this site wont do the code for you

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am not looking for code. I am not sure if wifi-direct is the right approach for this problem. Maybe there is a simpler, alternate solution? or some advice that shows how phones communicate in real-time?  I have done basic UI for the app.

Comment: i think your problem cannot be solved just using wifi-direct. you need a server. and what do you want to send? voice? message?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I don't think a server is necessary, there are plenty of apps that communicate directly over wifi (not necessarily through wifi-direct though), such as spell tower and other multi-player games.